# How do I prevent Eclipse from indexing things in Maven repo JAR files?

Tags: eclipse, maven, indexing, jar, eclipse-kepler

I’m using Eclipse Kepler on Mac 10.9.5, the M2Eclipse plugin and Maven 3.2.3.  I would like to prevent Eclipse from indexing JAR files, in particular things referenced in my M2_REPO directory.  Within Eclipse, I click Shift+Command+t, type “OrderServiceImpl” (A name of class in the project), and saw

```
OrderServiceImpl - org.mainco.subco.myproject.service - orders/src/main/java 
OrderServiceImpl - org.mainco.subco.myproject.service - M2_REPO/org/mainco/subco/orders/79.0.0-SNAPSHOT/orders-79.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar - /Users/davea/.m2/repository/org/mainco/subco/orders/79.0.0-SNAPSHOT/orders-79.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Is there a way I can prevent Eclipse from indexing things in JAR files?  I would like to exclude all of them but if that’s not possible, at least things included in my M2_REPO directory (dependencies brought in through my pom.xml file).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what Eclipse *indexes,* you can specify filters on what the "Open Type" window shows using [Working Sets](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcworkset.htm):

[image]

Comment: Good to know but that may not be what I'm asking.  I want to save the CPU cycles/resources/whatever that go into indexing things I don't want indexed.  Does the solution you list here prevent the actual indexing from taking place?

Comment: Not AFAIK. Have you really seen Eclipse spend that long indexing... anything? I frequently work with hundreds of projects and indexing isn't a bottleneck. (In my case, the bottleneck is maven downloading snapshots)